# Running PHPUnit test in PHPStorm from a Virtual Machine

Tags: debugging, phpunit, virtual-machine, phpstorm, remote-debugging

The project I am working on is running on a VM.
For debugging the application we use the following path mapping

`Settings->Language and frameworks -> servers:`

```
/Users/Oleg/dev/project -> /home/dev/ws/project
```

However, nothing I tried so far did not allow me to run and\or debug the PHPUnit unit tests in PHPStorm.

Comment: WebStorm? PHPUnit is for PHP projects .. and requires PhpStorm ...

Comment: My bad edited, tag was correct though :)

Comment: So .. 1) how do you run your PHPUnit tests? 2) PhpStorm version? 3) PHPUnit version and type of installation (PHAR/Composer etc)? 4) What kind of errors/problems do you get there? 5) How do you connect to VM (the files -- deployment: SFTP/shared folder etc)?  Screenshots please

Comment: Well the problem is that the php interpeter is not local but is located on the VM, and PHPStorm doesn't know how to cope with that

Comment: Please answer ALL questions -- not just one of them. Anyway: in latest stable version that's not a problem at all -- you just create and use "Remote PHP Interpreter" and run all tests via SSH.

Comment: Official manual: https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Running+PHPUnit+tests+over+SSH+on+a+remote+server+with+PhpStorm